# How to use Grunt to minify and substitute a template into an angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I have a `directive` in my angular code which has an inline `template` property for the sake of app load times. The template is becoming large and unwieldy so I thought about using a `templateUrl` property but I want to simplify my code without slowing down the load times.

So ... I was wondering if its possible to use `Grunt` to minify a html template file and then substitute the string right into the `template` property of a directive, and with such build magic get best of both worlds: ease of development and fast load times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [grunt-angular-templates](https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-angular-templates).

All you have to do, is putting your partials in external html files and referencing them as usual using the `templateUrl` attribute. `grunt-angular-templates` will minify all of your templates and put them into a single modules `$templateCache`.